# Two separate updates involving different columns in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

```
UPDATE users SET col1 = '' WHERE user_id IN (a, b)
UPDATE users SET col2 = '' WHERE user_id IN (c, d)
```

Is it possible to write a single update query that can provide the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
UPDATE users
    SET col1 = (CASE WHEN user_id IN (a, b) THEN '' ELSE col1 END),
        col2 = (CASE WHEN user_id in (c, d) THEN '' ELSE col2 END)
    WHERE user_id in (a, b, c, d);
```

Comment: I am getting a syntax error #1064 while using this, I don't what is causing the error. I am using this code.

`UPDATE tb_users   SET unique_device_id_reg = (CASE WHEN user_id IN (2403613, 2403614) THEN '' ELSE unique_device_id_reg END),    
           reg_device_token   = (CASE WHEN user_id in (2403615, 2403616) THEN '' ELSE reg_device_token END) 
    WHERE user_id in (2403613, 2403614, 2403615, 2403616)`

Comment: The query in your comment looks basically correct.  Perhaps you have stray non-ASCII characters in the statement.

Comment: how can I remove those?

Comment: @NawedDiwan . . . You can try re-typing the query.

Comment: in fact I am not able to do this also

 `UPDATE tb_users
SET reg_device_token = reg_device_token
WHERE user_id = 2403616`